# How to cut the text include HTML tag to expect length?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The first, I have a string(text has 245 characters):

```
var string = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book."
```

Then I write some html like this:

```
var stringHTML = "<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of <a href='#print'>the printing</a> and typesetting industry. <b>Lorem Ipsum</b> has been the <i>industry's<i> standard dummy <span>text ever</span> since the 1500s, when <strong>an unknown</strong> printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book</p>"
```

Then I need to cut it to 150 characters(150 characters will not include html tag)

==> `"Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 150."`

But I need the result will like this:

```
var resultExpected = "<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of <a href='#print'>the printing</a> and typesetting industry. <b>Lorem Ipsum</b> has been the <i>industry's<i> standard dummy <span>text ever</span> since the 150.</p>"
```

Any idea how do like that? If yes, please give me some example code.

Thanks for supporting.

Comment: https://github.com/arendjr/text-clipper

Comment: Thanks @RoryMcCrossan. This plugin save my life. It's awesome.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to trim the first 150 chars of your `stringHTML` string without losing any html tags.

```js
var stringHTML = "<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of <a href='#print'>the printing</a> and typesetting industry. <b>Lorem Ipsum</b> has been the <i>industry's<i> standard dummy <span>text ever</span> since the 1500s, when <strong>an unknown</strong> printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book</p>";
console.log(stringHTML.substring(0, 150));
```

And if you meant that you want the 150 chars count to ignore the html tags then what you can do is to loop through the string char by char and count your characters, when reaching a `<` char (or a preset sub-string like `<p`) you will stop the counting until you reach `>` after reaching 150 check you index (of the original string) and using that index use `substring(0, index)`.

Comment: Hi Lev, The substring will cut the html tag on the end. So we can't use this method.

Comment: You can check my explanation it can be modified to your needs, but i could see that you found your solution with text-clipper so there is no need to manually set this up.